# Pass props to a `react-bootstrap` component, with the correct types, in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-props

I'm using the `react-bootstrap` package, in React, and written in TypeScript.

I have a component that wraps the `Button` component from `react-bootstrap`, and I want to accept all props that `Button` accepts (and therefore, that the underlying HTML `button` element also accepts, like `style`), to this new component, so that I can pass them down to `Button`.

Simple example, with no types specified yet:

```js
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

function WrapperButton(props) {
  const { children } = props;

  return <Button {...props}>{children}</Button>;
}
```

In `react-bootstrap/Button.d.ts`, `<Button>` is declared with:

```js
declare class Button<
  As extends React.ElementType = 'button'
> extends BsPrefixComponent<As, ButtonProps> {}
```

But if I set `props: BsPrefixComponent<'button', ButtonProps>` then it doesn't accept attributes like `style` and `children`.

Is there a more appropriate type I could use, for this scenario?